# php array merge duplicate occure

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 2 array named data & data1 both are same set of key and value but data1 have some custom key & value
so i want to merge in this

```
data array

[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => 1
        [total] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 2
        [total] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => 3
        [total] => 3
    )

data1 array

[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => 1
        [total] => 1
        [custom] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 2
        [total] => 1
        [custom] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => 3
        [total] => 3
        [custom] => 1
    )

$test = array_merge(data,data1);
```

so i used array_merge(data,data1) it shows duplicate

after merge i got like this

```
print_r(test);
{"name":1,total":"1"}
{"name":1,"total":"1","custom":1}
```

Comment: What do you expect to obtain ?

Comment: if i print test i want like this only {"name":1,"total":"1","custom":1} one time

Comment: So, basically you want to print `$data1`. Also, these are not arrays - they are JSON objects. You have to `json_decode()` them before you can use them in PHP. See https://3v4l.org/RDre9

Comment: I'm sure its a typo when posting into the question, but `{"name":1,total":"1"}` is also missing a quote.

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

```
array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

Used array_merge() and then perform array_unique()